# Iterating Composition over a list of tuples

Tags: list-manipulation

I produce a function list with

```
Tuples[{a, r}, 2] 
(* {{a, a}, {a, r}, {r, a}, {r, r}} *)
```

where functions `a` and `r` represent adding some fraction and taking the reciprocal:

```
a[z_, fraction_] := z + fraction

r[z_] := 1/z
```

I want to `Composition[]` each of the ordered pairs in the tuples list, e.g.

`a[a[x,frac]]`, then `a[r[x]]`, etc. into a new list:

```
{a[a[x,frac]],a[r[x,frac]],r[a[x,frac]],r[r[x,frac]]}
```

with the values for each of the list elements being the computed values of each of the composed functions.

The second term above would look like this:

```
Composition[a, r][y]

(* 1/2 + 1/y *)
```

Comment: What is `r[x,frac]` supposed to return when you've only defined `r[z_]`? What about a[r[x,frac]]` when you've only defined `a` to take two arguments? e.g. The example you give at the end will evaluate to `a[1/y]` not `1/2+1/y`with `a`, `r` defined the way they are here.

Comment: Good point. My mistake. A single argument for both functions works just fine, since the fraction used in the add function a[] can be passed down from the calling function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you really want the functions to take different numbers of arguments (which is not clear from the question):

```
a[z_] := z + 1/2
r[z_] := 1/z

tuples = Tuples[{a, r}, 2]

Composition[##][x] & @@@ tuples
```

> {1 + x, 1/2 + 1/x, 1/(1/2 + x), x}

Comment: Thanks so much! I have almost no experience with that type of expression/notation, and had wondered if that was the way to go here. Took me a bit to see how it works, but it is clear to me now. So elegant and concise. And I really appreciate how quickly you solved this for me. As for the use of the fraction in the function a[], that can be a variable in the calling function.

Comment: See also the other [answer by march](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/130398/22013). If you find the answers given here useful, feel free to upvote them by clicking the top-oriented grey triangle. The answer you like most can be _accepted_ by clicking the grey checkmark.

Comment: If I wanted to get the successive compositions of each ordered pair from the inside out using ComposeList[], how would I have to modify the expression? In other words,  I want a list `{{x,a[x],a[a[x]]},...}`.

Comment: That looks more like a `NestList`. You already answered: [`ComposeList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComposeList.html). But do not extend the scope of the initial question in comments. It's better to ask a new one.

Answer (score 6):

I will redefine your functions so that they both take two inputs, and the both output `fraction` so that in the composition, we can keep track of what `fraction` is, even though `r` doesn't depend on it:

```
Clear[a, r]
a[{z_, frac_}] := {z + frac, frac}
r[{z_, frac_}] := {1/z, frac}
```

Then, we will define a function that takes as inputs `z` and `frac`, forms all compositions of the function, then applies the compositions to the inputs. Finally, at the end, we extract just the desired output:

```
applyComposition[z_, frac_] := First /@ With[
   {f = Composition @@@ Tuples[{a, r}, 2]},
   Through[f[{z, frac}]]
 ]
```

Then,

```
applyComposition[x, frac]
(* {2 frac + x, frac + 1/x, 1/(frac + x), x} *)
```

Comment: Thanks for an interesting different approach!

Answer (score 2):

A pure operator version of corey's answer  (i.e., a version without a pure function) could go:

```
tf = Through @* (Composition @@@ tuples)
```

> Through@*{a@*a, a@*r, r@*a, r@*r}

Then:

```
tf[x]
```

> {1 + x, 1/2 + 1/x, 1/(1/2 + x), x}